# Can't connect to Bitcoind remotely

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, client, json-rpc, bitcoin-cash

I am running a Bitcoin Cash node on my server, and starting it like this:

```
start bitcoind.exe --server=1 --rpcuser=user --rpcpassword=password --rest=1 --rpcport=8332 --datadir=F:\Bitcoin --bind=10.1.0.4 --testnet=1 --rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0
```

The node runs, and I can connect to it locally.

However, I can't connect to it remotely, from my C# application, using the BitcoinLib library:

```
ICoinService coinService = new BitcoinService(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Bitcoin_DaemonUrl"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Bitcoin_RpcUsername"],
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Bitcoin_RpcPassword"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WalletPassword"]);
```

I am getting this error:

> BitcoinLib: There was a problem sending the request to the wallet.
>   System: Unable to connect to the remote server.

I have created inbound/outbound rules in the server's firewall settings, allowing access to the 8332 port, and I think that `--rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0` should allow all IPs to connect to my node... So I really don't know what the problem is.

**Edit:** I can't access the node from https://bitnodes.earn.com/ either.

*Update:* the node has finished reindexing blocks, and I still can't connect to it remotely.

Comment: You're running in testnet mode (which Bitcoin Cash doesn't have), and trying to bind to the normal RPC port, and bitnodes don't support tesstnet.

Comment: @eponymous I have started it in main net mode now, and bitnodes still says it's unreachable. It says in the logs that it's "reindexing blocks" - will my server be unreachable untill the reindexing is done?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the solution didn't really have anything to do with bitcoind itself - I was running it on a virtual machine hosted on Azure, and I needed to create firewall rules for the port not only on the actual Windows machine, but also in the Azure portal!